# Why does an empty char type pointer returns "â" as the output?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

And why does it return "ä" now, when I return it along with an empty char variable?

Here is the code that I was working on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    //Declaring and defining a char array also adding up pointer as its elements 
    /*A char pointer with the stored address returns the value of that address but, an unassigned char pointer returns â as the output
     when I do not use an empty variable but, when I use an empty vairable it returns ä as the output*/
    char *A;
    char B = 'H';
    char *H;
    char C;
    A = &B;
    char arr[10] = {'a','b','c','d',*A,*H,C};

    //Traversing the array
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%c ",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

I just did not expected those symbols in the empty pointer char variable. I just need a good explanation for this.

Comment: You have undefined behavior with uninitialized variables

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value

Answer (score 1):

You don't give `H` a value so it points to garbage (you can't know anything about the value). `C` is similarly garbage.